# Issue connecting to remote Aerospike server via Go code running locally

Tags: go, aerospike

I have installed Go (1.8.0) on my Mac (10.10 and then upgraded to 10.12), and then followed the steps at https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go for getting the Aerospike client library on my machine.

We have code that we have created and works with our remote server IP address(es) for Aerospike on coworkers' machines as well as a VM running on Google Cloud.  This code does not work on my machine.  I have even tried the test code that is in the aerospike-client-go README, and I get the same error: `Failed to connect to host(s): [X.X.X.X:3000]; error: Connecting to the cluster timed out.`

I am able to ping those IP addresses on port 3000 without any issues.

Is there a configuration that I might be missing that might have to be changed (environmental variable, etc) to get this to go?

Comment: Can you simply telnet to that port (3000)? What does the aerospike.log say? Is the node up and ready? (Do you see the 'soon there will be cake' message?)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate this issue and sort it out. This happens when you connect from go-client, 1.16.7 version on my macbook. when i tried to connect a VM instance using its public ip address, the client used to timeout.

Reference Aero spike ticket :
https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/issues/31

Here is my go code of snippet

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"

    as "github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go"
    asl "github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/logger"
)

func main() {
    readPocDatafromAeroSpike()
}

func readPocDatafromAeroSpike() {
    log.Println("Connecting to aero spike")
    asl.Logger.SetLevel(asl.DEBUG)
    cp := as.NewClientPolicy()
    cp.Timeout = time.Duration(10 * time.Second)

    client, e := as.NewClientWithPolicy(cp, "publicIPOfInstance", 3000)
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal("Exception connecting aero spike cluster ", e.Error())
    }

    log.Println("Connected to Aero Spike now ", client.IsConnected())
    log.Println("done")
}
```

Following is the issue,when i ran the about code :

```
 09:53:58 Connecting to aero spike
 09:53:58 No connections available; seeding...
 09:53:58 Seeding the cluster. Seeds count: 1
 09:53:58 Node Validator has 1 nodes and they are: ["publicip":3000]
 09:53:59 Host `"publicip":3000` seems to be a load balancer. It is going to be replace by `privateip:3000`
 09:54:04 Connection to address `"privateip":3000` failed to establish with error: dial tcp "privateip":3000: i/o timeout
 09:54:08 Failed to connect to hosts:
 09:54:08 Failed to connect to host(s): ["publicip":3000]; error: Connecting to the cluster timed out.
 09:54:08 Exception connecting aero spike cluster Connecting to the cluster timed out.
```

In order the sort this issue, a following configuration change needs to be added in the aero spike server to start accepting connection from the public address ( the address which is configured in the client )

You need to configure access-address in `aerospike.conf`

Reference :

https://docs.aerospike.com/server/operations/configure/network/general#what-is-access-address

https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/how-to-configure-aerospike-for-use-with-ipv6-or-mixed-ipv4-ipv6/5218

```json
network {
        service {
                address any
                port 3000
                access-address {publicIP-here}
        }
```

Restart the aero spike server and your client should be able to connect.

Thanks.